# Transpose based on column names Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that was originally in an unstructured JSON format. I normalized the JSON and am having trouble transposing the dataframe based on the normalized column structure

Here's what the dataframe looks like

| id | name | attributes_0_color | attributes_0_pet | attributes_1_color | attributes_1_pet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | red | dog | purple | parrot |
| 2 | Bill | blue | cat | orange | hamster |

How can I get the dataframe to look like this?

| id | name | color | pet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | red | dog |
| 1 | John | purple | parrot |
| 2 | Bill | blue | cat |
| 2 | Bill | orange | hamster |

Answer (score 4):

With [`lreshape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.lreshape.html) :

```
out = (pd.lreshape(df, {"color": ["attributes_0_color", "attributes_1_color"],
                       "pet": ["attributes_0_pet", "attributes_1_pet"]})
            .sort_values(by="id")
)
```

Output :
​
print(out)

```
   id  name   color      pet
0   1  John     red      dog
2   1  John  purple   parrot
1   2  Bill    blue      cat
3   2  Bill  orange  hamster
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very similar use case to `pd.wide_to_long`:

```
temp = df.set_index(['id','name'])

# split the column names by `_`, ignore `attribute` part
# print `temp` after this command to see what it does
temp.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(map(lambda x: x.split('_')[1:], temp.columns)))

# expected output
out = temp.stack(level=0).reset_index(level=-1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   id   name    color      pet
0   1  John      red       dog 
1   1  John   purple    parrot
2   2  Bill     blue       cat 
3   2  Bill   orange   hamster
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'attributes_\d_', '', regex=True)
pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :4], df.iloc[:, [0, 1, 4, 5]]]).sort_values('id')
```

Output:

```
   id  name   color      pet
0   1  John     red      dog
0   1  John  purple   parrot
1   2  Bill    blue      cat
1   2  Bill  orange  hamster
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [janitor.pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

names_pattern = ['color', 'pet']
df.pivot_longer(index = ['id', 'name'], 
                names_to = names_pattern, 
                names_pattern = names_pattern, 
                sort_by_appearance=True)
   id  name   color      pet
0   1  John     red      dog
1   1  John  purple   parrot
2   2  Bill    blue      cat
3   2  Bill  orange  hamster
```

You can also use the `.value` placeholder:

```py
df.pivot_longer(index = ['id', 'name'], 
                names_to = '.value', 
                names_pattern = r".+_(.+)", 
                sort_by_appearance=True)
   id  name   color      pet
0   1  John     red      dog
1   1  John  purple   parrot
2   2  Bill    blue      cat
3   2  Bill  orange  hamster
```